# failed to deploy jsf application and gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I've tried to deploy my jsf application to google app engine but when it seems good, in the console show this:

> C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\build_appengine_deployutils_SifaeJSF.xml:53: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.31\config\user\ant-macros.xml:95: 
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:791)

I'm working in netbeans 8 and tried  edit the build-impl.xml in the line javac.fork to false, but the problem still persist, any suggestions?

EDIT: the file build_appengine_deploytuls_SifaeJSF.xml is autogenerated by the gae api the trace begin with this line in this file:

```
<enhance_war war="${build.web.dir}">
        <args>
            <arg value="-enhancerVersion"/>
            <arg value="v2"/>
        </args>
    </enhance_war>
```

This is the line the get the error cause in ant-macros.xml file:

```
<enhance failonerror="true" api="@{api}">
    <args/>
    <classpath>
      <pathelement path="${appengine.tools.classpath}"/>
      <pathelement path="@{war}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
      <fileset dir="@{war}/WEB-INF/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    <fileset dir="@{war}/WEB-INF/classes" includes="**/*.class"/>
  </enhance>
```

Comment: what is unclear about the error _" The filename or extension is too long at "_

Comment: The files that console trace shows me are auto generated by the gae api, I think the error is in the classpath but I don't know

Comment: then run in debug more and set a breakpoint...

Comment: all seems good, but i think the size of my jsf application exceeds the size permited in gae, thanks!

Comment: You **think…* The exception states otherwise, but if that realy is the problem, file an issue at gae to improve the error reporting

Comment: The size of my application is over 150 Mb, the maximum file size supported in gae is 32 Mb

Comment: Great you found something. See my comment above